# heroku + node + express + hogan wont start, no info in the logs

Tags: node.js, heroku, express

My Heroku app won't start, when I load the page in the browser it just gives me the generic

> **Application Error**
>
> An error occurred in the application and your page could not be
>   served. Please try again in a few moments.
>
> If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

And my checking my heroku logs pretty much says nothing other than "`State changed from starting to crashed`".

```
2015-04-01T23:10:13.629849+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v12 created by xxxx@gmail.com
2015-04-01T23:10:13.629849+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 7d3ab9f by xxxx@gmail.com
2015-04-01T23:10:13.748810+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-04-01T23:10:15.398769+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node routes/index.js`
2015-04-01T23:10:17.007727+00:00 app[web.1]: Detected 512 MB available memory, 512 MB limit per process (WEB_MEMORY)
2015-04-01T23:10:17.007751+00:00 app[web.1]: Recommending WEB_CONCURRENCY=1
2015-04-01T23:10:18.163323+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2015-04-01T23:10:18.184341+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

When I load the page in the browser and see the error above, the log shows

```
2015-04-01T23:11:20.387769+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=surrealist-debate.herokuapp.com request_id=2c304a35-950a-422d-9174-4d558cbd4d40 fwd="172.3.184.57" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-04-01T23:11:20.727572+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=surrealist-debate.herokuapp.com request_id=474f2a28-31eb-4c93-9371-db91ec0f4427 fwd="172.3.184.57" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Here is my **package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "surrealist-debate",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.12.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.4",
    "debug": "~2.1.1",
    "express": "~4.12.2",
    "hjs": "~0.0.6",
    "morgan": "~1.5.1",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.2.0"
  }
}
```

I also get no clues when running locally through **foreman** `foreman start web` with this **Procfile**

`web: node routes/index.js`

**foreman** just gives me this error:

```
16:31:34 web.1  | started with pid 12073
16:31:34 web.1  | exited with code 0
16:31:34 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
```

I *can* however run it straight locally with **DEBUG**:
`DEBUG=surrealist-debate:* ./bin/www`

And it works locally:
`surrealist-debate:server Listening on port 3000 +0ms`

WHAT is going on?!  How can I get this to run on Heroku and foreman and not just exit and crash right away with no info?

Comment: It's throwing an H10 error:  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h10-app-crashed  You might check for other logs to see if there's more detail than what you're seeing.

Comment: Yup @Michael Blankenship, I checked that page on Heroku's site already and it definitely seems like a crashed web dyno but what other logs can I check and how do I prevent the dyno from crashing? The "heroku logs" command shows all logs combined.

Comment: I'm on Openshift, btw.  And when I tail the logs I also get all the logs combined--it can be a little noisy as logs go.  What I found, though, is that on Openshift I can fire up an SSH session, simply navigate to the logs folder under my app-root folder and then read the logs independently there.  Hopefully you're familiar with UNIX shell commands like ls and cd and tail.  When in the logs folder you might enter the command to see the last 50 lines:  "tail -n 50 nodejs.log"

Comment: If the nodejs.log says nothing about the error I'd suggest then doctoring up your server.js or app.js so that it adds some console.log() commands throughout.  Add about four of them, equally spaced like console.log('1'); console.log('2'), etc.  Push it, run it, review the logs to see the last number seen.  Remove and add more console.log()'s to frame the offending code so that you can isolate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, seems like the issue was just the **Procfile**!  It was trying to run `routes/index.js` when it should have been pointing to `bin/www` (which does its thing then executes index.js, which in turn serves the correct views/index.hjs)

To all others who see similar error with no info in the logs, check your **Procfile** ;)